# Mail not sending using tank_auth in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using tank auth and sending mail is not working for me. I am now checking it for forgot password. I tried a lot, referring the various posts regarding the same. But nothing worked for me. I am using zohomail. Following is the code I have tried so far.

I have added the following to **config/email.php**

```
$config['protocol']='smtp';
$config['smtp_host']='ssl://smtp.zoho.com'; 
$config['smtp_port']='465';
$config['smtp_timeout']='30';
$config['smtp_user']='myemail'; 
$config['smtp_pass']='mypass'; 
$config['charset']='utf-8';
$config['newline']='\r\n';
```

No other changes to any file are made. The output I am getting is like the following:

```
220 mx.zohomail.com SMTP Server ready March 10, 2014 12:35:17 AM PDT 

hello: 250-mx.zohomail.com Hello localhost (61.3.161.53 (61.3.161.53))
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250 SIZE 25000000
from: 250 Sender  OK
to: 250 Recipient  OK
data: 354 Ok Send data ending with .

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 13:05:15 +0530
From: "NOS-7094" <wm@nnnn.com>
Return-Path: <wm@nnnn.com>
Reply-To: "NOS-7094" <wm@nnnn.com>
To: myemail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Forgot_your_password_on_NOS-7094=3f?=
X-Sender: wm@nnnn.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <531d6b335db13@nnnn.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_531d6b335db5e"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_531d6b335db5e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Hi user,

Forgot your password, huh? No big deal.
To create a new password, just follow this link:

http://localhost/workspace/project/index.php/auth/reset_password/1/95e4b28205efe5da5da2c6a7f625b58c

You received this email, because it was requested by a N-7094 user. This
is part of the procedure to create a new password on the system. If you DID
NOT request a new password then please ignore this email and your password
will remain the same.


Thank you,
The N-7094 Team


--B_ALT_531d6b335db5e
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Create a new password on NOS-7094</title></head>
<body>
<div style=3D"max-width: 800px; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0;">
<table width=3D"80%" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0">
<tr>
<td width=3D"5%"></td>
<td align=3D"left" width=3D"95%" style=3D"font: 13px/18px Arial, Helvetica,=
 sans-serif;">
<h2 style=3D"font: normal 20px/23px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0=
; padding: 0 0 18px; color: black;">Create a new password</h2>
Forgot your password, huh? No big deal.<br />
To create a new password, just follow this link:<br />
<br />
<big style=3D"font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><b><a href=3D"=
http://localhost/workspace/project/index.php/auth/reset_password/1/95e4b2820=
5efe5da5da2c6a7f625b58c" style=3D"color: #3366cc;">Create a new password</a=
></b></big><br />
<br />
Link doesn't work? Copy the following link to your browser address bar:<br =
/>
<nobr><a href=3D"http://localhost/workspace/project/index.php/auth/reset_pas=
sword/1/95e4b28205efe5da5da2c6a7f625b58c" style=3D"color: #3366cc;">http://=
localhost/workspace/project/index.php/auth/reset_password/1/95e4b28205efe5da=
5da2c6a7f625b58c</a></nobr><br />
<br />
<br />
You received this email, because it was requested by a <a href=3D"http://lo=
calhost/workspace/project/index.php" style=3D"color: #3366cc;">NOS-7094</a> =
user. This is part of the procedure to create a new password on the system.=
 If you DID NOT request a new password then please ignore this email and yo=
ur password will remain the same.<br />
<br />
<br />
Thank you,<br />
The N-7094 Team
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
    </html>

--B_ALT_531d6b335db5e--
```

Please help me to send mail.

Comment: on localhost? Do you have a local mail server?

Comment: yes from localhost..using smtp we can send mails from localhost right??